# Blazor wasm: Services.AddHttpClient with AddHttpMessageHandler and IHttpClientFactory

Tags: service, blazor, httphandler, ihttpclientfactory

in my blazor Net7 application I configure these services for add jwt token in request header (AuthenticationHandler).

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerApi")
            .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["WebApi"] ?? ""))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerApi"));
```

I would expect that when I inject an object of type IHttpClientFactory and with it create an httpClient object of name "ServerApi" (_factory.CreateClient("ServerApi").GetAsync(...)) that the http request have the authorizazion header, added by the handler AuthenticationHandler. But this doesn't happen.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Better state the version. 8 is just around the corner and something changed with named clients.

Comment: @HH Net7 thank you